# How does the overdrive voltage of diode connected load in a common source with a diode connected load limit voltage swing?

Tags: amplifier, cmos

[image]

I get how the threshold voltage of M2 limits the upper bound for voltage swing, but the book I am reading says the overdrive voltage of M2 also limits the voltage swing. The only reason I can come up with is that the operating point gets set when you bias the circuit i.e Vout = Vdd-Vov. Now, when an input signal is applied then output signal gets superimposed on the Vout DC level, thereby reducing the voltage swing level.

Can someone tell me if I am right or explain if I am wrong?

Comment: Forget about biasing and "superimposing" for a moment. What happens when you increase Vin? M1 delivers more current into M2. What happens to the voltage (Vds) of M2 when the current is increased? So that means Vout is pushed down, what does that mean for the Vds of M1? What will happen when the Vds of M1 is "not enough"?

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But I am not able to understand how this limits the voltage swing level.

Comment: *But I am not able to understand how this limits the voltage swing level.* Then answer: *What will happen when the Vds of M1 is "not enough"?* What mode of operation will M1 be in: 1) when the Vds of M1 is "large enough" and 2) when Vds of M1 is "not enough" (for M1 to be able to deliver all the current that it wants). Saturation or linear mode? Realize that the amplifier works based on the fact that M1 converts a voltage to a current and M2 converts that current back to a voltage. The amplifier will only be linear if those relations are eachother's inverse.

Comment: To ensure that the circuit works as a good amplifier we have to make sure M1 works in saturation .So, the min level for th output voltage swing is decided by the overdrive of M1 i.e Vgs-Vth.I am fine with this. What bothers me is the fact that the book I am reading say the overdrive of M2 also limits the voltage swing.

Comment: The explanation for this is as follows: suppose you have established the gain as 10 then the gain of the Common source with diode connected load can also be seen as the ration of the overdrives of the two mosfets. So, assuming the overdrive of M1 is 100 mv the overdrive of M2 is 1V.Now, since Vov=Vgs-Vth we get Vgs2=0.8 (assuming Vth2 is 0.2).After calculating this the author says this severely limits the voltage swing.My question is how does this limit the voltage swing?The output voltage can still swing between Vdd-Vth2 and Vov of M1.

Comment: *So, assuming the overdrive of M1 is 100 mv the overdrive of M2 is 1V...we get Vgs2=0.8* It doesn't work like that. If the overdrive voltage of M2 is 1V the Vgs of M2 is Vov + Vt = 1.2 V. When Id of M2 is close to zero, the Vgs of M2 is Vth. Then as the current increases, Vov adds to that.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong calculation. So, what I have understood is that Vout can vary between Vdd-Vth2 and Vov of M1 .So, To achieve a certain gain the Vgs2 wil have a certain value this decides the value of Vout before an input signal is applied as Vout=Vdd-Vgs2.This value of Vout for a high gain might drive M1 into triode.Is this the point you were trying to emphasize ?

Comment: Ok I finally understood what you were saying .Thanks.

Comment: *This value of Vout for a high gain might drive M1 into triode* YES, I wrote "Realize that the amplifier works based on the fact that M1 converts a voltage to a current and M2 converts that current back to a voltage" that is only going to work properly (linear transfer) if both devices are in **saturation mode**. If you force M1 into triode (not so much due to large gain but due to a large input signal resulting in large output signal!) then M1 will be in triode and M2 still in saturation: the signal transfer will not be linear anymore.

Comment: Bonus questions, if you can answer this, you understand this circuit: 1) M1 needs to be in saturation, will M2 ever go into triode mode? 2) What determines the gain? Suppose M1 and M2 have a certain W/L resulting in some gain. Now I **double** the W of M1 so M1 is 2W/L while M2 is W/L, what happens to the gain. Same but now for M1 is W/L but M2 is 2W/L.

Comment: M2 cant go to triode because of it's biasing. It might get switched off though. The gain is determined by the square root of W/L ratios of M1 and M2  i.e (W/L)1/(W/L)2.So doubling W/L of M1  results the gain multiplying with root of 2 while doubling W/L of M2 divides the gain by root of 2.

Comment: *M2 cant go to triode because of it's biasing* So if I change the biasing I can get it into triode mode? How about: since it is "diode" connected, Vds = Vgs so Vds is always larger than Vds,sat, because Vds,sat = Vgs - Vth.

Comment: yeah I meant the same thing just used wrong words to explain it.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Is there a really good application that I am not seeing?

Answer (score -1):

Using 2 identical FETs the Rds will be equal then Vgs1=Vgs2= Vt giving a small signal unity gain.  For the maximum linear swing with unity gain, Vin- must = Vt for M1 and Vdd-Vout+ must equal Vt for M2.